# Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type on Pointers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a link to log the usernames `uNameAddr`.
URL: `http://zzz.com?username=MyNameIsJack`.
So I need to do it like `"http://zzz.com?username=" + uNameAddr`.
But I'm getting an error. I guess my syntax seems wrong?

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://zzz.com?username=" + uNameAddr);
```

The whole code:

```
char *uNameAddr = (char*) ExeBaseAddress + 0x34F01C;
printf("%s \n", uNameAddr);

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://zzz.com?username=" + uNameAddr);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

---

*UPDATE*

So I tried:

```
char username[512];
strcpy ( username, "http://zzz.com?username=" );
strcat ( username, uNameAddr );
```

But the application crashes when processing this part.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, username);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenate char array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218290/concatenate-char-array-in-c)

Comment: If you're truly using C++ though, consider using `std::string` which actually overloads `operator+` for string concatenation.

Comment: What do you see if you do `printf("|%s|\n", username);`?

Comment: @Barmar It prints the correct data, but app crashes.

Comment: @user1553142, then the problem is elsewhere, it's not _this_ what crashes the application, get rid off all the other unrelated code, just define strings and `printf`. It will not crash

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;
 ...
 ...

 string str1 = "Hello world.";
 const char* cstr = " Goodbye.";

 string str2(cstr);
 string combined = str1 + str2;
```

Comment: This still crashes the application. Hmmm.

Comment: What type of argument is curl_easy_setopt() expecting?

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLoption option, parameter);

Comment: For the URL option, it requires `char*`.

Comment: 'parameter' is not a type.  I'm guessing you aren't a C/C++ programmer.  If you need a C style string, then use combined.c_str() as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
char username[512];
strcpy ( username, "http://zzz.com?username=" );
strcat ( username, uNameAddr );
```

> But the application crashes when processing this part.

No, the compiler would give you an error saying uNameAddr is undeclared before you got to your function call.  Here's the deal: C++ is not a language you can casually mess around with.  It is a complicated language that is very exacting.  You can't fudge things when you are coding--you have to KNOW that what you are typing is exactly right.

I suggest you forget about your function call and try to get an example working that just prints out your string.  Once you get that working, you can try to call your function with the string.