# When does printf("%s", char*) stop printing?

Tags: c, printf

In my class we are writing our own copy of C's malloc() function.  To test my code (which can currently allocate space fine) I was using:

```
char* ptr = my_malloc(6*sizeof(char));
memcpy(ptr, "Hello\n", 6*sizeof(char));
printf("%s", ptr);
```

The output would typically be this:

```
Hello
Unprintable character
```

Some debugging figured that my code wasn't causing this per se, as ptr's memory is as follows:

[24 bytes of meta info][Number of requested bytes][Padding]

So I figured that printf was reaching into the padding, which is just garbage.  So I ran a test of:
`printf("%s", "test\nd");` and got:

```
test
d
```

Which makes me wonder, when DOES printf("%s", char*) stop printing chars?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It stops printing when it reaches a null character (`\0`), because `%s` expects the string to be null terminated (i.e., it expects the argument to be a C string).

The string literal `"test\nd"` is null terminated (all string literals are null terminated).  Your character array `ptr` is not, however, because you only copy six characters into the buffer (`Hello\n`), and you do not copy the seventh character--the null terminator.

Answer (score 5):

James is correct about printf stopping when it gets to the null character, and Uri is correct  that you need to allocate a 7-character buffer to hold "hello\n".

Some of the confusion with terminators would be mitigated if you used the usual C idiom for copying a string: `strcpy(ptr, "Hello\n")`, rather than `memcpy`.

Also, by definition, sizeof(char) == 1 in C, so `6*sizeof(char)` is redundant

Comment: 6*sizeof(char) may be redundant but it is, in my opinion, good practice for the simple reasons (1) if a char on some new architecture is not = 1 or (2) this code is ported to wchar_t....

Comment: It wouldn't just be a new architecture, it would be a new language. If `sizeof(char) != 1`, you are no longer programming in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1

Answer (score 3):

C strings are null terminated (there's a \0 character at the end), that's how C knows when to stop printing or dealing with the buffer as a string . It is your responsibility to never put a string in a longer space than what you have allocated.

Note that Hello\n is not a six character string, it is actually a seven character string.
You use five for the Hello, one for the newline, and one for the null terminator.

Trying to fit 7 characters into a six character buffer is considered a bug, I am not sure if it is responsible for the problems you are currently having, but it seems like the copying of 6 characters would not copy the null terminator. So I would actually expect your print to go beyond the Hello and into some actual junk.

Comment: Dur, I should be using \0 to terminate strings? Dur Dur Dur

Comment: You don't have to add \0 yourself. When you create a literal string or get one as input, C adds it for you. You don't actually see the \0. That "Hello\n" string is seven characters if you looked at the actual assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

when it reaches a zero. you need 7 chars.