# Traversing Two Dimensional Array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

How come `Line 1` and `Line 2` have more than ten **x**(s) when the loop should end at ten given the condition of `ii < 10`?

I am trying to understand how these two dimensional arrays work, any advice is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[3][10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){
            name[i][ii] = 'x';
        }
    }


    printf("Line 1: %s.\n", name[0]);

    printf("Line 2: %s.\n", name[1]);

    printf("Line 3: %s.\n", name[2]);


    return 0;
}
```

FIX:

Thanks to everyone's comments I managed to fix the code. The problem was that I was not reserving one space for the NULL terminator at the end of the array. Since I wanted ten **x**(s), the solution is to increase the size of the two dimensional array so that it has space for the NULL terminators.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[4][11];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){
            name[i][ii] = 'x';
        }
    }


    printf("Line 1: %s.\n", name[0]);

    printf("Line 2: %s.\n", name[1]);

    printf("Line 3: %s.\n", name[2]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You **must** reserve one character for your NUL terminator, taht is `name[i][9]` **must** be 0.

Comment: @tadman ah, you are completely right. I do not know how I missed that. Thanks. Should I take down the question?

Comment: Possible dupe target : [When does printf(“%s”, char*) stop printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2726301/327083)

Comment: You might want to fix it, then post your fix as an answer so you can learn from this mistake. Happens to the best of us!

Comment: `for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){ name[i][ii] = 'x'; }` --> `for(int ii = 0; ii < 9; ii++){name[i][ii] = 'x'; } name[i][ii] = '\0';`

Comment: You didn't need to increase the size from 3 to 4. Only the size from 10 to 11 needed to be increased for the null character

Comment: For your fixed code, you still need to follow 4386427's fix to actually store the nul char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been discussed in comments, the problem with your code was that you didn't add a NUL to terminate the strings.

However, I'll post an answer as **your fix isn't really a fix**

Two things to mention:

1. You don't need to extend the dimension of the array to `[4][11]` but only to `[3][11]`. It's only the number of chars in each string that need to be increased to make room for the termination. Changing `[3]` will give you room for an extra string and that is not what you are looking for. So use `[3][11]`
2. Your fix still doesn't add the NUL terminator. Remember that a local variable isn't automatic initialized so you need to do it yourself. In other words - you need some code that explicit sets `name[i][10]` to NUL.

This is how memory is looking in your original code, your fix and how you really want it.

[image]

Below is two ways to get what you want.

Option 1:

```
char name[3][11];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){
        name[i][ii] = 'x';
    }

    // Add NUL to the end to get a correct C style string
    name[i][ii] = '\0';
}
```

Option 2:

```
// Explicit initialize the whole array to zero
char name[3][11] = { 0 };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){
        name[i][ii] = 'x';
    }
}
```

I prefer option 1 but option 2 will also do the job.