# Scanning into structs

Tags: c

I want to ultimately insert strings from a file into elements in structs and can't get it right. Can you see what is wrong here?

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char file_name[10] = "map7.map";
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

    int a = 1;
    int *pnumberOfRows = &a;
    fscanf(fp,"%d",pnumberOfRows);

    typedef struct {
        bool visited;
        char *cityName;
    } map;

    map *ver = malloc(sizeof(map)*2*(*pnumberOfRows));

    fscanf(fp,"%s",ver[1].cityName);
    printf("%s",ver[1].cityName);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're simply missing to allocate space for the `char *cityName` fields, which makes you `fscanf` onto an unallocated pointer. You could either provide a fixed-with field, e.g.

```
typedef struct {
    bool visited;
    char cityName[81];
} map;
```

for a maximum length of 80 characters (i.e. *excluding* `\0`) or determine the length of the city names in the file beforehand and then allocating memory to the field using

```
ver[0]->cityName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(stringLength+1));
```

Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`, so feel free to leave it away, but see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3162048/195651) for more information. I left it here for the sake of being expressive about what you want to achieve.

Also, don't forget to `free` the memory you `malloc`'d at the end and also close the file descriptor after you're done (i.e. `fclose(fp);`).

Comment: `*stringLength` certianly should be `*(stringLength+1)`.  Why suggest casting the result of `malloc()` (not needed) and multiplying by `sizeof(char)`  which in 1?  Alternate: `ver[0]->cityName = malloc(stringLength + 1);`

Comment: I am assuming `stringLength` to contain the terminator as per the example above, but you're certainly right about `sizeof(char)`; it's just a matter of personal taste to be explicit about what you want to achieve. The compiler is likely to optimize it away anyways.