# Doubt in malloc. C (Linux)

Tags: c, malloc, posix, buffer

In the following code,what is the meaning of     `buf = malloc(n * sizeof(char));`

is **n*sizeof(char)** necessary,if yes.. please elaborate.

```
int n;

char* buf;

fstat(fd, &fs);

n = fs.st_size;

buf = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

**EDIT1** And What if I write **(n*sizeof(double))**

Comment: It's not necessary, because `sizeof(char)` is [always 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1).  However, some people prefer it for uniformity; it's evaluated at compile-time, so it doesn't matter much.

Comment: It's always 1 in C99 compliant compilers, which you should always take with a grain of salt. Even most modern compilers aren't "fully" C99 compliant.

Comment: @David, it's required since [C89](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), if not before.

Comment: The definition of `sizeof` has *always* been in units of `char`. Nothing else would make any sense. A `char` is one `char` so its size is 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `malloc` function allocates bytes and takes as input the number of bytes you would like to allocate.  The `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes for a given type.  In this case a `char` is 1 byte, but in the case of an `int` it is most likely 4 bytes or `double` is most likely 8 bytes.  The expression `n * sizeof(char)` converts the number of `char` into the number of bytes that are desired.

In the case illustrated, using `char`, computing the number of bytes is probably not needed, **but** it should be done as it helps to convey your intent.

What the expression is doing is allocating the desired amount of memory needed to hold at most `n` number of `char`'s and returning you a pointer, `buf`, to the beginning of that allocated memory.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is asking because sizeof(char) is defined to always be 1.

Comment: I thought of that, but all that it will ever cost anyone is a multiply by 1 instruction in the event they are doing `char`.  I think conveying intent here weights out.

Comment: ...and the compiler will optimize away the multiplication by 1.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Bingo ;) Just for intent

Answer (score 1):

The ISO standard defines a `byte` as the same size as a `char`.

You never need `sizeof(char)` for `malloc`