# 'strcpy' with 'malloc'?

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

Is it safe to do something like the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* msg;

    strcpy(msg, "Hello World!!!");  //<---------

    printf("%s\n", msg);

    return 0;
}
```

Or should the following be used?

```
char* msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
```

Comment: You need the malloc, otherwise msg is just a dangling pointer.

Comment: Use `malloc`, but remove the cast and `sizeof(char)`. The correct usage is `char *msg = malloc(15);`

Comment: Also `malloc()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>` not `<malloc.h>`

Comment: And the return value from `malloc()` should **ALWAYS** be checked: `char *msg = malloc(15); if (msg == NULL) /* not ok to proceed */;`

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski: if you don't check you have no way of knowing whether it "worked". Returning `NULL` is malloc's way of telling you something went wrong.

Comment: For people (like me) curious why omitting `sizeof(char)` is OK in this instance (as in  @R..'s comment): [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215445/1110928) explains that `sizeof(char)==1` per the C99 standard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your original code does not assign msg. Attempting to strcpy to it would be bad. You need to allocate some space before you strcpy into it. You could use malloc as you suggest or allocate space on the stack like this:

```
char msg[15];
```

If you malloc the memory you should remember to free it at some point. If you allocate on the stack the memory will be automatically returned to the stack when it goes out of scope (e.g. the function exits). In both cases you need to be careful to allocate enough to be able to copy the longest string into it. You might want to take a look at strncpy to avoid overflowing the array.

Comment: if the size of msg is less than the string's length, say "char msg[3]; strcpy(msg, "abcdefg");", would be ok? If now, I cout msg, will the output be "abcdefg"?

Comment: No it will not. `char msg[3]` allocates space for 3 characters. You cannot copy 8 characters into that space (7 letters plus a null terminator).

Answer (score 39):

strdup does the malloc and strcpy for you

```
char *msg = strdup("hello world");
```

Comment: strdup is not C standard, not C89 and not C99

Comment: POSIX is a standard. There are a lot of things that we use that aren't C89 or C99. That isn't reason not to use something so simple. Please use strdup before writing a dense macro like MYSTRDUP(). strdup takes 1 line to implement as a function, and frankly, should be in the standard.

Comment: Certainly, but it is worth mentioning that this is in POSIX.

Comment: just had weird issues with strdup but only on Win 10, malloc+strcpy instead then it works?!

Comment: I would be *very* suspicious of a statement like 'just had weird issues with strdup'.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I think the reason it isn't in the C standard is because it allocates memory and only the malloc/calloc set of operators are supposed to do that. Otherwise, it causes a side effect. This is why it has never been included.

Comment: `strdup` is included in C2x. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup

Answer (score 2):

The first version is not safe. And, `msg` should be pointing to valid memory location for "Hello World!!!" to get copied.

```
char* msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
strcpy(msg, "Hello World!!!");
```

Comment: don't cast the return of `malloc` and don't use `sizof(char)`.

Comment: why not sizeof(char)?

Comment: char is guaranteed to be 1 byte in c

Comment: @yampelo so `sizeof(char)` is both correct and clear but redundant. No need to say 'dont use'

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#define MYSTRDUP(str,lit) strcpy(str = malloc(strlen(lit)+1), lit)
```

And now it's easy and standard conforming:

```
char *s;
MYSTRDUP(s, "foo bar");
```

Comment: except in the case that malloc failed

Comment: missing a (char*) cast  #define MYSTRDUP(str,lit) strcpy(str = (char*)malloc(strlen(lit)+1), lit)

Answer (score 1):

```
 char* msg;
 strcpy(msg, "Hello World!!!");  //<---------Ewwwww
 printf("%s\n", msg);
```

This is UB. No second thoughts. `msg` is a wild pointer and trying to dereference it might cause segfault on your implementation.

`msg` to be pointing to a valid memory location large enough to hold `"Hello World".`

Try

```
char* msg = malloc(15);
strcpy(msg, "Hello World!!!");
```

or

```
char msg[20]; 
strcpy(msg, "Hello World!!!");
```

Comment: (UB == undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the space. Use `malloc` before the `strcpy`.