# Segmentation fault in constructor when using strcpy

Tags: c++

Hi guys I'm writing a program that reads NMEA sentences for a university assignment and I'm having trouble with segmentation fault. Can anyone help me fix it, please?

```
NmeaSentence::NmeaSentence(std::string sentence) {
    const char *temp = sentence.c_str();
    char *c_sent;
    strcpy(c_sent, temp);
    char *pch;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SENTENCE_PARTS; i++){
        pch = strtok(c_sent, ",");
        this->sentenceParts[i] = pch;
    }
    this->sentence = sentence;
    this->sentenceType = sentenceParts[0];
}
```

The error seems to be happening at strcpy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strcpy with malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354933/strcpy-with-malloc)

Comment: On a side note, why not using `std::string` everywhere? Is there a specific need that forces you to manipulate strings through `(const) char *`?

Comment: You're using `strtok`. That's plenty wrong. Consider using Boost.Tokenizer, or `split` from Boost.StringAlgo.

Comment: @Will It seems you did not read all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate memory for `c_sent`. That's undefined behaviour.

Use `char *c_sent = new char[sentence.size() + 1];`. I've added space for the null terminator. Don't forget to call `delete[] c_sent;` before the function exits.

(By the way, `temp` is valid for the lifetime of `sentence`, unless it's modified in any way.).

Comment: Actually it is valid until sentence is modified, so it would be prudent to make sentence const.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I'm new to C++

Comment: @heinrichj: that's a very good point. Better still, pass `const std::string& sentence` as the function parameter.

Comment: @Will If you're new to C++, the best advice I can give you is to use `std::string` as much as possible. Drop all the old `char*` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary string c_sent is uninitialized.

```
char * c_sent
```

to

```
char * c_sent = strdup(sentence.c_str());
```

Dont forget to free, before exit.

```
free(c_sent);
```

You won't need temp this way.

Comment: We're in C++ here, I'd advise against using `free` etc.

Comment: Well, if you are using strtok, you might as well use strdup and free.

Comment: @Bathsheba you must use `free` with `strdup`, although using `strdup` is [may not be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984948/why-is-strdup-considered-to-be-evil) a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The member function has several defects.

If the parameter of the function is not changed then it would be better to declare the function as

```
NmeaSentence::NmeaSentence( const std::string & sentence);
```

As it was already said you did not allocate memory where you are going to copy sentence. Pointer c_sent was not initialized by the address of an allocated memory.

The second defect is that pch always points to the same address in c_sent because you are incorrectly using function strtok. You should use it the following way

```
char *pch = strtok(c_sent, ",");
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SENTENCE_PARTS && pch; i++){
    this->sentenceParts[i] = pch;
    pch = strtok( NULL, ",");
}
```

Also it is not clear how you will determine how many parts the string contains.