# Concatenate four string constants into one

Tags: c++, c, string

I have two string constants `const char *` like this:

```
const char * p1 = "abcd";
const char * p2 = "efgh";
```

I want to convert these into a single string so that it becomes a file name:

```
const char * filename = "abcd_efgh.txt";
```

I tried to concatenate the `char *` but failed. Kindly guide me as to how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You want to concatenate strings, not pointers...

Comment: @R..:  Sorry I took the liberty of editing the question before reading your comment lest it nor confuse anybody. @jv42: Somewhat brutal re-tagging, it is as much applicable C++ as it is C.

Comment: @Clifford: I don't like `std::string` much, but using `const char*` in C++ is really asking for troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `sprintf()`

```
char buffer[strlen(p1) + strlen(p2) + 6];
sprintf(buffer, "%s_%s.txt", abcd, efgh);
```

(You're adding 6 for the `_`, `.txt`, and the `\0` to terminate the string; 1 + 4 + 1)

Comment: Change it to `snprintf`. `sprintf` is difficult to use safely, deprecated, and should not be used.

Comment: Meh, we somehow managed to be able to count prior to c99. I don't find basic arithmetic daunting.

Comment: @Brain:  ... except that the variable-length array rather implies C99.  If p1 and p2 where const-arrays rather than const-pointers, `sizeof` could be used in C89/90 or C99.

Comment: @R.: Note that `sprintf` is none more or less safe than `snprintf` in this case, because `strlen` is not. You allocate a buffer to concat the strings into. `sprintf` could fail, but only if the buffer is not large enough (string not properly zero-terminated). But then, `strlen` would already fail (and, on top of that, allocating a buffer of possibly unlimited size on the stack can cause a crash too).

Comment: @R: `sprintf` has been deprecated by who?

Comment: You could spell the `6` as `sizeof "_.txt"`, to make it clear where it comes from.

Answer (score 4):

`char*` are *pointers*, i.e they hold the address of the memory segment where the data is stored. You need to allocate a new, large enough buffer and then use the `strcat()` function to concatenate the strings.

This is really the C way to do this, not the C++ way. In C++ you should use a string class, such as `std::string` which handles all the buffer allocation stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `strcat` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/):

```
/* strcat example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[80];
  strcpy (str,"these ");
  strcat (str,"strings ");
  strcat (str,"are ");
  strcat (str,"concatenated.");
  puts (str);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the filename string const, which is too restrictive for what you want to do at runtime, but can be done by the pre-processor at compile time, using the *adjacent string rule*:

```
#define PART1 "abcd"
#define PART2 "efgh"

const char* p1 = PART1 ;
const char* p2 = PART2 ;

const char* filename = PART1 "_" PART2 ".txt"
```

However if you don't need filename to be a `const` use one of the already proposed solutions.

Comment: Actually it was my edit that added `const`. Assigning a string literal address to a non-const `char *` is bad style that is accepted just because of backward compatibility (some compiler even give a diagnostic message for it).

Answer (score 0):

```
const std::string p1 = "abcd";
const std::string p2 = "efgh";

std::string filename = p1 + "_" + p2 + ".txt";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
char name1[] = "my_demo";
char name2[] = "_file.txt";

char* filename = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name1) + strlen(name2) + 1));
strcpy(filename, name1);
strcat(filename, name2);

printf("Filename is: %s \n", filename);

free(filename);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Filename is: my_demo_file.txt
```

Comment: -1: this is bad for two reasons: 1) `sizeof(name1)` is 4 by pure coincidence and not because those strings have 4 chars, 2) there is no need to set the ending NUL, `strcat` does that already.

Comment: It's still somewhat broken - you need to change `sizeof` to `strlen` in two places, otherwise you are allocating too many bytes. Also sizeof(char) == 1 by definition, so this is redundant.

Comment: Great, thanks @Paul! Regarding `sizeof(char)`, it's a style issue.

Comment: Removed my -1: but I agree with Paul that `sizeof(char)` simply shows you may think it's not 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1/2215454#2215454