# having problems with write() function in C

Tags: c, pointers

Given parts of my code:

```
char bmpheader[54] = {0x42, 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

char bmpimagedata[36] = {0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x66, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00};


while (i < 54) {
    printf("%c", bmpheader[i]);
    write (socket, bmpheader[i], 1);
    i++;
}
while (j < 36) {
    printf("%c", bmpimagedata[j]);
    write (socket, bmpimagedata[j], 1);
    j++;
}
```

I'm getting an error on my compiler saying `passing argument 2 of 'write' makes pointer from integer without a cast` for both write functions. I'm not too sure about the function's arguments itself (is the third argument correct?).

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) function accepts a *pointer* to what you want to write out; you're passing it a `char` (which is being promoted to an `int`).

The minimal fix would be to change this:

```
write (socket, bmpheader[i], 1);
```

to

```
write (socket, &bmpheader[i], 1);
```

...but there are better ways.

You can just let `write` write out all 54 bytes itself:

```
write (socket, bmpheader, 54);
```

Or if you really want to do it a `char` at a time, you could use a pointer:

```
int i;
char *p;
for (i = 0, p = bmpheader; i < 54; ++i, ++p) {
    printf("%c", *p);
    write (socket, p, 1);
}
```

In either case, you want to avoid that magic number `54` and take it from the data. Since `sizeof(char)` is [always one byte in standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1), you can use `sizeof` without doing the ugly `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` thing:

```
int i;
char *p;
for (i = 0, p = bmpheader; i < sizeof(bmpheader); ++i, ++p) {
    printf("%c", *p);
    write (socket, p, 1);
}
```

...but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution than that.

You can also use `putchar` (fairly lightweight) instead of `printf` (fairly heavyweight):

```
int i;
char* p;
for (i = 0, p = bmpheader; i < sizeof(bmpheader); ++i, ++p) {
    putchar(*p);
    write (socket, p, 1);
}
```

And I used to do things like this with pointer arithmetic, no idea whether they're bad practice in the modern world:

```
char* p;
char* endp;
for (p = bmpheader, p = bmpheader + sizeof(bmpheader); p < endp; ++p) {
    putchar(*p);
    write (socket, p, 1);
}
```

Comment: Ahh I knew there was some catch, didn't see the `&`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

signature for [write](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/write.htm) is

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

So second parameter should be a pointer and you are passing an actual value not a pointer. The following should help

```
write (socket, bmpheader + i, 1);
write (socket, bmpimagedata + j, 1);
```

But why not do

```
write (socket, bmpheader, sizeof(bmpheader)/sizeof(*bmpheader));
write (socket, bmpimagedata, sizeof(bmpimagedata)/sizeof(*bmpimagedata));
```

and checking the return value of course

Answer (score 0):

if you check prototype of [write function](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/write.html), you'll see that second parameter is a char*. In your case, you're giving it a cell or your array, then a char.
You should write:

```
write (socket, &(bmpheader[i]), 1);
```

Of course, this is far from being the most efficient, you could write directly

```
write (socket, bmpheader, 54);
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut, so I don't need to loop all those hex values?

Comment: No, you don't : data are consecutive, you can burst them out :-)

Answer (score 0):

write (socket, &bmpimagedata[j], sizeof(bmpimagedata[j]));
the second argument should be pointer
and the third is the data size to be written

Comment: in my case, would 1 work instead of sizeof (since they're all 1 byte size).

Answer (score 0):

bmpimagedata[j]

is an integer you want to use
&bmpimagedata[j]

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to...

```
write (socket, bmpimagedata + j, 1);
```

... it'll work. but you don't have to send your data one byte at a time, that's why third parameter is length.

Also have you considered looking up reference documentation for write() function to see exactly how it works and what it accepts?  Learning to read and interpret documentation may not be easy, but in the long term would be much more beneficial than asking questions, "I'm not sure what third parameter is"

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly many weird/convoluted suggestions.

The canonical way to write out these two arrays is:

```
write(socket, bmpheader, sizeof bmpheader);
write(socket, bmpimagedata, sizeof bmpimagedata);
```

There's absolutely no point in doing computations to figure out the number of elements, involving the size of a single character, or anything. Just write the entire array, once for each, and be done.

Plus, of course, track if you succeeded or not (maybe only a part was written), and handle that.

Comment: I think this looks the most clean.