# structure data alignment for char

Tags: c

I want to know if I had such a construction:

```
typedef struct {
    char element;
} element_t;
```

So now is the condition:

```
sizeof(elem.element) == sizeof(element_t) == 1
```

true only for some architectures or it is always like that? I mean, any alignment can occur here, so can it be:

```
(sizeof(elem.element) == 1) != (sizeof(element_t) == 4)
```

if data in structures are aligned to 4-byte boundaries in a 32-bit architecture.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(elem.element)` is guaranteed to be 1 (but there is no guarantee that it will hold only 8 bits).

There is no guarantee that `sizeof(element_t) == 1`, though on all practical architectures, I believe it will be of size 1.

Comment: Supporting Jon's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1