# Is arithmetic overflow equivalent to modulo operation?

Tags: c, overflow, modulo, integer-arithmetic

I need to do modulo 256 arithmetic in C. So can I simply do

```
unsigned char i;
i++;
```

instead of

```
int i;
i=(i+1)%256;
```

Comment: well, since C99 there is `stdint.h` and you can simply use `uintXX_t` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Comment: While this works, it falls into the category of overclever tricks that are likely to get removed by another developer that thinks your trick is a bug. Being explicit about your intent with modulo prevents such.

Comment: If you don't have to rely on anyone else maintaining your code, then yes. I just don't see why you would. The extra work in maintaining confusing code is not worth it.

Comment: Remember `%` is remainder not modulo! although modulo  == remainder for positive numbers. Both code pieces are not equivalent because first give you modulo whereas second gives remainder (your `i` is `int` not `unsigned int`).

Comment: @Mgetz There are no other developers since it's for a lab assignment where I've to implement RC4. I've decided not to do it anyway since it's better to be explicit rather than implicit, and I better not do esoteric tricks esp when someone is grading it..

Comment: @v3ga - it's good that you asked; it led to an interesting discussion, and the insight that "not every byte is 8 bits" - which was news to me. You are right that you are better off with the "explicit" code that makes it obvious what you are doing - and a good compiler knows fast tricks for doing `%256` so you don't have to micro-optimize. There is a LOT to be said for writing clear code - expecially if it's a lab and gets graded! Thanks for starting an interesting discussion.

Comment: It was news to me too (actually I get a lot of such stuff out of most questions on C).

Comment: @v3ga I will suggest you if you use first version (or either suggested by Alexandre C.) You can always add a sort comment in code that explain that you evaluating mod 256 that will be fine. Just add `//trick to eval mod 256`. I good program is one who knows more than one ways. code like iitians :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. There is nothing that guarantees that `unsigned char` has eight bits. Use `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`, and you'll be perfectly fine. This requires an implementation which supports `stdint.h`: any C99 compliant compiler does, but older compilers may not provide it.

Note: unsigned arithmetic never overflows, and behaves as "modulo 2^n". Signed arithmetic overflows with undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2485710: Even MSVC has `stdint.h` now that they try to implement C++11.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2215454/1967396 for a reference that says "char is always one byte" in C99

Comment: @Floris: Yes, but one C byte is not necessarily 8 bits. It is *defined* as the size of one `char`.

Comment: yes, but it's always a requirements and more often than not I see any kind o requirements from people using `C`, really really old implementations are, for example, quite popular in the embedded world.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I see - you are right. That makes your answer better than mine.

Comment: @user2485710: You are right about the embedded world. On the desktop, this is no longer a problem though.

Comment: And the OP it's not even mentioning kind of machine that he is targeting, so you just don't know and you should specify this in your answer; also other people may need this piece of information.

Comment: @user2485710: Done. Since byte tricks are quite common in such environments, a word of caution is indeed necessary.

Comment: Even with a C99 compliant compiler, all the `intN_t` and `uintN_t` types are optional, and are not guaranteed to be available. On any system that doesn't have 8-bit bytes (admittedly, probably unusual) they likely won't be available.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: One example that I know of is a particular 16-bit Texas Instruments DSP embedded platform that only supports word addressing, so everything is at least 16 bits. `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizef(int) == 1 == 16 bits`. The assumption suggested in this answer wouldn't work there.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the behavior of both of your examples is the same. See **C99 6.2.5 §9 :**

> *A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>   because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type.*

Answer (score 5):

Very probably yes, but the reasons for it in this case are actually fairly complicated.

```
unsigned char i = 255;
i++;
```

The `i++` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`.

(Well, almost. `i++` yields the value of `i` *before* it was incremented, so it's really equivalent to `(tmp=i; i = i + 1; tmp)`. But since the result is discarded in this case, that doesn't raise any additional issues.)

Since `unsigned char` is a narrow type, an `unsigned char` operand to the `+` operator is promoted to `int` (assuming `int` can hold all possible values in the range of `unsigned char`). So if `i == 255`, and `UCHAR_MAX == 255`, then the result of the addition is `256`, and is of type (signed) `int`.

The assignment implicitly *converts* the value `256` from `int` back to `unsigned char`. Conversion to an unsigned type is well defined; the result is reduced modulo `MAX+1`, where `MAX` is the maximum value of the target unsigned type.

If `i` were declared as an `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned int i = UINT_MAX;
i++;
```

there would be no type conversion, but the semantics of the `+` operator for unsigned types *also* specify reduction module `MAX+1`.

Keep in mind that the value assigned to `i` is mathematically equivalent to `(i+1) % UCHAR_MAX`. `UCHAR_MAX` is *usually* `255`, and is guaranteed to be *at least* `255`, but it can legally be bigger.

There could be an exotic system on which `UCHAR_MAX` is too be to be stored in a signed `int` object. This would require `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, which means the system would have to have *at least* 16-bit bytes. On such a system, the promotion would be from `unsigned char` to `unsigned int`. The final result would be the same. You're not likely to encounter such a system.  I think there are C implementations for some [DSPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) that have bytes bigger than 8 bits. The number of bits in a byte is specified by `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>`.

`CHAR_BIT > 8` does not necessarily imply `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`. For example, you could have `CHAR_BIT == 16` and `sizeof (int) == 2` i.e., 16-bit bytes and 32 bit `int`s).

Comment: Technically `i++` is equivalent to making a copy of `i` before incrementing it and using the old copy in the expression where the post-increment occurred. `++i` would be the true equivalent to `i = i + 1`/`i += 1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
unsigned char c = UCHAR_MAX;
c++;
```

Basically yes, there is no overflow, but not because `c` is of an unsigned type. There is a hidden promotion of `c` to `int` here and an integer conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` and it is perfectly defined.

For example,

```
 signed char c = SCHAR_MAX;
 c++;
```

is also not undefined behavior, because it is actually equivalent to:

```
c = (int) c + 1;
```

and the conversion from `int` to `signed char` is implementation-defined here (see c99, 6.3.1.3p3 on integer conversions). To simplify `CHAR_BIT == 8` is assumed.

For more information on the example above, I suggest to read this post:

"The Little C Function From Hell"

http://blog.regehr.org/archives/482

Comment: Thanks for the link to "The little C function from hell". I had seen it before, but I had forgotten to bookmark it at the time. As I couldn't recall the exact title I found it impossible to Google for it.

Comment: The sum of two `unsigned char` values won't overflow, but on machines where `sizeof (int)` is two, the product of two `unsigned char` values could overflow.  Historically, the fact that the standard would allow a compiler on a 16-bit machine to do anything it liked with `unsigned char x=255; x*=255;` wasn't seen as a defect because in practice even compilers which used 16-bit `int` would behave sensibly.  The fact that such code yielded Undefined Behavior was seen as a theoretical issue, rather than an opportunity for compilers to negate laws of time and causality.

Answer (score 3):

There's another alternative that hasn't been mentioned, if you don't want to use another data type.

```
unsigned int i;
// ...
i = (i+1) & 0xFF; // 0xFF == 255
```

This works because the modulo element == `2^n`, meaning the range will be `[0, 2^n-1]` and thus a bitmask will easily keep the value within your desired range. It's possible this method would not be much or any less efficient than the `unsigned char`/`uint8_t` version, either, depending on what magic your compiler does behind the scenes and how the targeted system handles non-word loads (for example, some RISC architectures require additional operations to load non-word-size values). This also assumes that your compiler won't detect the usage of power-of-two modulo arithmetic on unsigned values and substitute a bitmask for you, of course, as in cases like that the modulo usage would have greater semantic value (though using that as the basis for your decision is not exactly portable, of course).

An advantage of this method is that you can use it for powers of two that are not also the size of a data type, e.g.

```
i = (i+1) & 0x1FF; // i %= 512
i = (i+1) & 0x3FF; // i %= 1024
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine because it should just overflow back to 0. As was pointed out in a comment on a different answer, you should only do this when the value is unsigned, as you may get undefined behavior with a signed value.

It is probably best to leave this using modulo, however, because the code will be better understood by other people maintaining the code, and a smart compiler may be doing this optimization anyway, which may make it pointless in the first place. Besides, the performance difference will probably be so small that it wouldn't matter in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if the number of bits that you are using to represent the number is equal to number of bits in binary (unsigned) representation (100000000) of the divisor -1 
which in this case is : 9-1= 8 (char)