# Calculating checksum (16 bit) in c

Tags: c, checksum

I am being asked to do a checksum on this text with the bit size being 16:
"AAAAAAAAAA\nX"

At first the description seemed like it wanted the Fletcher-16 checksum. But the output of Fletcher's checksum performed on the above text yielded **8aee** in hex. The example file says that the modular sum algorithm (minus the two's complement) should output **509d** in hex.

The only other info is the standard "every two characters should be added to the checksum."

Besides using the generic Fletcher-16 checksum provided on the corresponding Wikipedia page, I have tried using this solution found here: [calculating-a-16-bit-checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980000/calculating-a-16-bit-checksum) to no avail. This code produced the hex value of **4f27**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding the data seeing it as an array of big-endian 16-bit integers produced the result `509d`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "AAAAAAAAAA\nX";
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; data[i] != '\0' && data[i + 1] != '\0'; i += 2) {
        int value = ((unsigned char)data[i] << 8) | (unsigned char)data[i + 1];
        sum = (sum + value) & 0xffff;
    }
    printf("%04x\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay I can see where I was misunderstanding was now. Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: For the pedantic: use `unsigned char*` for data access, else `data[i] != '\0'` (2 zeros) and `(unsigned char)data[i]` is incorrect for the dinosaur non-2's complement machines.  `(unsigned char)data[i] << 8` risks overflow with 16-bit `int`.  Better to use `unsigned sum` with `"%04x"` anyways to avoid 8 digit output when `sum < 0` on 32-bit machines.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why is `data[i] != '\0'` incorrect?

Comment: Rare non-2's complement machines have +0 and -0 or +0 and trap.  In C, a string's final _null character_ is only the +0 one.  See "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)." 7.24.1 3  Accessing `data[i] != '\0'` can trigger on both +0 and -0.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was attempting to add for a 32-bit checksum doing it this same way and can’t seem to grasp the concept. I tried incrementing by 4 and tried various oring combinations. Would I still bit shift left 8 or would it be 16?

Comment: @Mook The shift will be 24, 16, and 8 (and 0), according to the position of each byte.

Comment: @MikeCAT and then I would or each of those bit shifts with the corresponding position in the array and add to checksum, right?

Comment: @Mook Exactly, go ahead to implement that and test.

Comment: @MikeCAT Alright I've edited it some to look like this:
`for(i = 0; data[i] != '\0' && data[i + 1] != '\0' && data[i + 2] != '\0' && data[i + 3] != '\0'; i += 4) {
        int value = ((unsigned char)data[i] << 8) | (unsigned char)data[i + 1];
        int valueTwo = ((unsigned char)data[i] << 16) | (unsigned char)data[i + 2];
        int valueThree = ((unsigned char)data[i] << 24) | (unsigned char)data[i + 3];
        sum = (sum + value + valueTwo + valueThree) & 0xffffffff;
    }
`
and get an output of **c3c3c529**. I am not sure if that would be correct or not.