# code snippet lack of understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am boxing with a C code snippet I need to convert.
One of the functions is as follows:

```
+(float) calcTemp:(NSData *)data {
    char scratchVal[data.length];
    [data getBytes:&scratchVal length:data.length];
    UInt16 temp;
    temp = (scratchVal[0] & 0xff) | ((scratchVal[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
    return (float)temp;
}
```

This line I just can't seem to grasp:

```
temp = (scratchVal[0] & 0xff) | ((scratchVal[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
```

i know its probably a novo question (but I am a noob^), if someone could explain that line to me i would greatly appreciate it. In particular the things with address references and the operator uses.

In the code snippet I don't see why they call getBytes:length method on data, since its not being used. But mainly, Im just trying to understand the line that I pointed out.

Comment: [Bitwise operations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Comment: It's assembling a 16-bit value from the first two bytes in the scratchVal buffer.  More inexplicable is 'return (float)temp;'

Comment: What are you converting this to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
temp = (scratchVal[0] & 0xff) | ((scratchVal[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
```

is creating an unsigned 16-bit integer value from two bytes originating in `scratchVal`.  A single `&` in this context is not the address operator but bitwise AND.  So the lower byte of `temp` is set from the first byte contained in `scratchVal`, and the upper byte of `temp` is set by left-shifting the second byte contained in `scratchVal`.  The two resulting numbers are joined together using bitwise OR `|`.  To avoid sign extension or other unwanted bits the masks `0xff` and `0xff00` are used to ensure all undesirables are zero.

Presented visually, if `scratchVal` contains the bits `aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb` in the first two bytes then temp will end up as an unsigned integer with the bit pattern `bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa`.

The second question asked why they're calling `-getBytes:length:`.  The line

```
[data getBytes:&scratchVal length:data.length];
```

reads the bytes from `data` into the `scratchVal` temporary buffer.

In response to the question in the comment

> why it is needed to left shift the bits to concatenate them

A simple assignment won't work.  Assuming again that `scratchVal` is a `char` buffer containing the bits `aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb`, the code

```
temp = scratchVal[0];
```

would make temp equal to the `UInt16` equivalent of the bits `aaaaaaaa`.   You can't use addition because the result will be whatever value comes from adding the two bytes together (`aaaaaaaa` + `bbbbbbbb`).

Using real numbers as an example, suppose the first two bytes of `scratchVal` are equal to `0x7f 0x7f`.

```
temp = scratchVal[0] + scratchVal[1];
```

Turns out to be `0x7f + 0x7f` = `0xfe` which is not the purpose of this code.

Building the value using OR can be better understood by breaking it down into steps.

The first part of the expression is `scratchVal[0] & 0xff` = `0x7f & 0xff` = `0x7f`

The second part is `(scratchVal[1] << 8) & 0xff00` = `(0x7f << 8) & 0xff` = `0x7f00 & 0xff` = `0x7f00`

The final result in this case is `0x7f | 0x7f00` = `0x7f7f`.

Comment: I thought the char type was always 1byte?; at least thats what I've read. if I made a char variable[10] would it be 10 bytes? It still seems kind of difficult for me to grasp this, and why it is needed to left shift the bits to concatenate them. I appreciate your explaining though

Comment: A `char` is almost always one byte (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1).  See my edit for why you need to shift the bits left.

Comment: Thanks for your more detailed answer. I think using hexadecimal doesn't simplify the point though; since the shifting is one bitwise. Anyway, I think what I have trouble understand is when you have a byte and shift it left by 8, doesn't that mean that you will overwrite the byte "to the left" of the shifted byte. Inthis case scratchVal[1] overwriting scrathval[0]. And i don't understand how shifting by 8 (hence a full byte) will put scratchVal[1] in front of scratchVal[0]. Sorry if my question are not so wise, but I have just been trying to read up on things after this post. Thanks again

Comment: Shifting left does overwrite the bits to left but you're doing so in a temporary so `scratchVal[0]` isn't overwritten.  You're creating two temporary values and then joining them together.