# Memory using malloc() without a cast in c

Tags: c, malloc

Just wondering, I have allocated memory using `malloc` without a cast.  e.g

```
 char *ptr = malloc(26);
```

It's compiling successfully with GCC without an error. Is it safe to allocate memory using this expression?

Also, Is there any difference between following expression?

```
char *ptr = malloc(26);
```

and

```
char *ptr = (char*) malloc(26 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) `sizeof(*char)` or `sizeof(char)`?

Comment: [sizeof(char)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I guess (hope..) it is a typo...

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` doesn't harm, and its not necessary to multiply by `sizeof(char)`, since `sizeof(char)` is by definition exactly `1`.

Comment: he asks if it is okay to not use a cast in the first question.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe. It is often done, because you just have to change the type of `*ptr` and not the cast so it is more maintainable.

`malloc` gives you a `void*` which can be implicitly cast to any other pointer.

There should be no difference between the statements (if you use `sizeof char` and not `*char`)  in the second question, as the `char` should always be the smallest memory unit.

`sizeof char*` btw is not the `sizeof char`.  `sizeof char*` gives you the size of a pointer, which probably is 4 or 8 depending on your architecture.

The best way would be `char *ptr = malloc(26 * sizeof *ptr);` again this is more maintainable, because you just have to change the datatype of `*ptr`.

Comment: 1) Not having to specify the type is the least reason not to cast. 2) There are no implicit casts in C! 3) An implicit **conversion** is not "optional" (there is no "can be", but it either is done or not. Whether it is done is defined by the language standard.

Comment: About the "best way", there is a discussion, wheter to use `sizeof` always function-like, i.e. with the operand in parentheses or not. For expressions, this is not necessary (it is for types, though), but always using them makes usage uniform, althought eh parentheses are strictly part of the operand, not the `sizeof`.

Comment: whether parentheses are used is up to personal taste with the "best way" I meant he should get the size of the variable not the data type so it is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Olaf would you be so kind to elaborate the point about conversion and casts? I am not sure I understand your point.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Type conversion (e.g. the standard integer conversion) and pointer conversions are explained in the standard). As are casts. Basically a cast is not done automatically.