# Appending char to C array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a string declared as such:

`char *mode_s = (char *)calloc(MODE_S_LEN, sizeof(char));`

How can I add a char to the end of the array?

Comment: "available position": what does it mean?

Comment: @Arkadiy, I mean concatenate

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so you have a memory chunk `MODE_S_LEN` bytes long. These can be accessed from `mode_s` at indices 0 through `MODE_S_LEN-1`, so `mode_s[MODE_S_LEN-1]` is the last char in your array. Don't forget to make sure `calloc` gave you a valid memory chunk rather than NULL

Comment: First, [don't cast the result of `malloc` and friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Second, [`sizeof(char)==1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8).

Comment: @n.m. This code was supplied in the assignment and I'm not supposed to modify it.

Comment: This is not a "declaration of a string". There is no such thing as a "declaration of a string".

Comment: 1) A pointer is not a string. 2) A pointer is not an array. 3) Don't cast the result of `calloc` & friends or `void *` in general. 4) Don't use unnecessary or not understood casts at all. 5) `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition. It is useless.

Comment: Please learn about "C strings" (you can google this exact term).

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume " first available position " means at index 0.

```
char *mode_s = (char *)calloc(MODE_S_LEN, sizeof(char));
*mode_s='a';
```

To store a character at an arbitrary index n

```
*(mode_s+n)='b';
```

Use pointer algebra, as demonstrated above, which is equivalent to

```
mode_s[n]='b';
```

One sees that the first case simply means that n=0.

If you wish to eliminate incrementing the counter, as specified in the comment bellow, you can write a data structure and a supporting function that fits your needs. A simple one would be

```
typedef struct modeA{
  int size;
  int index;
  char *mode_s;
}modeA;
```

The supporting function could be

```
int add(modeA* a, char toAdd){
  if(a->size==a->index) return -1;
  a->mode_s[index]=toAdd;
  a->index++;
  return 0;
}
```

It returns 0 when the add was successful, and -1 when one runs out of space.

Other functions you might need can be coded in a similar manner. Note that as C is not object oriented, the data structure has to be passed to the function as a parameter.

Finally you code code a function creating an instance

```
modeA genModeA(int size){
  modeA tmp;
  tmp.mode_s=(char *)calloc(size, sizeof(char));
  tmp.size=size;
  tmp.index=0;
  return tmp;
}
```

Thus using it with no need to manually increment the counter

```
modeA tmp=genModeA(MODE_S_LEN);
add(&tmp,'c');
```

Comment: Wat? Why are you using such bizarre syntax? Use `mode_s[n] = 'b'`.

Comment: Seeing that pointers are giving him trouble, I showed explicit pointer notation. I added the equivalence of notations after your comment.

Comment: @ŽigaSajovic Thanks, it did occur to me that I could do it your way, however that would require me to increment a counter for every element. Is there not a simpler way to concatenate?

Comment: @MartinRand I added a simple implementation of a data structure that automates what you want. In C, you usually have to code the data structure you need.  I hope this is OK, I don't see any other way of such automation in C (besides coding a different data structure that is).

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function to concatenate a character to a string in C.  You can easily define such a function:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strcatc(char *str, char c) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    str[len++] = c;
    str[len] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

This function only works if `str` is allocated or defined with a larger size than its length + 1, ie if there is available *space* at its end. In your example, `mode_s` is allocated with a size of `MODE_S_LEN`, so you can put `MODE_S_LEN-1` chars into it:

```
char *mode_s = calloc(MODE_S_LEN, sizeof(*mode_s));
for (int i = 0; i < MODE_S_LEN - 1; i++) {
    strcatc(mode_s, 'X');
}
```