# In C, what is the size of a long for a 32-bit machine and for a 64-bit machine?

Tags: c, long-integer

Is it correct that a `long` in C has a size of 4 bytes for a 32-bit platform and 8 bytes for a 64-bit platform?

Comment: Typically, but not necessarily.  If you want a type of a fixed size, use `int32_t` or `int64_t`.

Comment: `long` has a minimum size of 32 bits, that's it.

Comment: Depends on the specific platform. `long` is at least 32 bits, but quite often it's 64 bits. `int` is at least 16 bits and it never has more bits than `long`. These are all the guarantees the language makes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: Depends on the *data model*, they have formal names.  LLP64 and LP64 are the common ones.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models.

Comment: Sorry, hans, `LLP64 and LP64 are the common ones.` it is not common, it is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `long` (and the sizes of objects generally) is determined by the C implementation, not the platform programs execute on.

Generally speaking, a C implementation is a compiler plus the libraries and other supporting software needed to run C programs.<sup>1</sup> There can be more than one C implementation for a platform. In fact, one compiler can implement multiple C implementations by using different switches to request various configurations.

A general C implementation typically uses sizes for `short`, `int`, and `long` that work well with the target processor model (or models) and give the programmer good choices. However, C implementations can be designed for special purposes, such as supporting older code that was intended for a specific size of `long`. Generally speaking, a C compiler can write instructions for whatever size of `long` it defines.

The C standard imposes some lower limits on the sizes of objects. The number of bits in a character, `CHAR_BIT`, must be at least eight. `short` and `int` must be capable of representing values from −32767 to +32767, and `long` must be capable of representing −2147483647 to +2147483647. It also requires that `long` be capable of representing all `int` values, that `int` be capable of representing all `short` values, and `short` be capable of representing all `signed char` values. Other than that, the C standard imposes few requirements. It does not require that `int` or `long` be a particular size on particular platforms. And operating systems have no say in what happens inside a programming language. An operating system sets requirements for running programs and interfacing with the system, but, inside a program, software can do anything it wants. So a compiler can call 17 bits an `int` if it wants, and the operating system has no control over that.

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The C 2011 standard (draft N1570) defines an implementation, in clause 3.12, as a “particular set of software, running in a particular translation environment under particular control options, that performs translation of programs for, and supports execution of functions in, a particular execution environment.”

Comment: C implementations generally need to conform to the ABI of the OS.

Comment: @Barmar: The OS is part of the implementation.

Comment: If that's true, then 32-bit OS = 32-bit C, 64-bit OS = 64-bit C, right?

Comment: @Barmar: No. General-purpose computers are, for practical purposes, Turing complete. This means you can execute any computation on any general-purpose computer (up to the physical bounds of the hardware). You could write a C compiler with 16-bit `int` on a 64-bit machine, and you could write a C compiler with 64-bit `int` on a 16-bit machine. The C standard does not require a C implementation to provide a direct interface to the operating system. It only requires the standard library routines, and those can be written to perform any necessary adjustments to work with the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is up to the implementation!

The only rules are `char` must be `CHAR_BIT` wide, and the sizes must be: `char <= short <= int <= long <= long long`, and `char` must be at least 8 bits, `short` at least 16 bits, `long` at least 32 bits, and `long long` at least 64 bits.

So actually all integer types (except long long) could be 32-bits wide and the C Standard is perfectly fine with that as long as `CHAR_BIT` is set to 32.

Comment: i dont think so. sizeof(char) is defined as 1. it would be weird to have all sizes be a multiple of 4 bytes

Comment: @pm100: sizeof is defined in numbers of chars. Not bytes. So sizeof(char) is always 1. Even if it is 32 bits wide.

Comment: @pm100 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8

Comment: @pm100: The C standard defines a byte as an “addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment.” A C implementation may use 32-bit bytes.

Comment: @ZanLynx: There are additional rules. `CHAR_BIT` must be at least 8, and, in effect, `short` and `int` must be at least 16 bits, and `long` must be at least 32.

Comment: @ZanLynx In C, a `char` is one "byte" *by definition*. A byte, as C defines the word, is at least 8 bits, but can be more. So `sizeof` is defined in terms of chars and, equivalently, in terms of bytes.

Comment: just saying it would be wierd to have a computer with no object smaller that 32 bits