# How much Memory allocation there will be in the pointer array

Tags: c++, c, memory

In the following statement:

```
char *myarray[] = {"Amir"};
```

For pointer myarray[], how many bytes of memory has been allocated?

Comment: `myarray[]` is not a pointer. It is actually nothing at all, because `myarray[]` is not an lvalue, it is just a declarator syntax. `myarray` is an array, `myarray[0]` is a pointer. `myarray[0]` points to the first element of a string literal. You get the size of a `thing` on **your** target system with `sizeof thing` - what does it say?

Comment: Remember to take into account that it is illegal, a compiler error, to assign a string literal (`const char []`) to a non-`const` pointer in modern C++.

Comment: And it is valid C, hence I believe the c++ tag is erroneous... but who knows. Also, what is `Char`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think OP meant to say `char`, not **Char**

Comment: Then I guess that's one more thing that OP would like to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS Architecture. Because it is an array of `char *`, It will take size equivalent to one pointer in this case.

For 32-bit addressing, it will take 4 bytes.

For 64-bit addressing, it will take 8 bytes.

Comment: C and C++ both place the null terminator.

Comment: @user4581301 After posting the answer, I just figured out that it is array of `char *`, not character array. Sorry for that.

Comment: @KunalPuri size of `char` is always 1 = 1 byte.

Comment: ... but byte need not be 8 bits... it is nevertheless called a byte by the C standard.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In CPP also, 1 byte means 8 bits as far as I know.

Comment: The classic Crays made pretty much everything 32 bits. This lead to much fun porting code. More reading  at [Are there machines, where sizeof(char) != 1, or at least CHAR_BIT > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8)

Comment: @KunalPuri now you'll know further: *"The fundamental storage unit in the C ++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain
any member of the basic execution character set (5.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8
encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the **number of which is implementation-defined.**"*

Comment: A C or C++ implementation may choose the number of bits in a byte but it may not change the identity byte === character type.