# Initializing a char* and std::string with bytes

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++17

Is the following implementation-defined:

```
char *cp = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";
```

and as well as:

```
std::string = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";
```

The `char` means `signed char` on my compiler (MSVC 2015).

I figured that I can't do the following:

```
unsigned char *cp = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";
```

`"\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8"` are bytes in range 0 - 255, hence my question is:

Does the above depend on the compiler?

Comment: `char` is never same type as as `signed char` even when `char` is a signed type.

Comment: string literals are `const`. What do you mean with "I can't do" ?

Comment: What is the question? `std::string = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";` doesn't compile

Comment: Okay, I changed `signed char` to `char` but `char` becomes `signed char` on my compiler.

Comment: @user963241 what do you mean by "becomes `signed char` on my compiler."?

Comment: `char` can be signed or unsigned, in either case it is not the same type as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, its a quirk of the language, dont try to get the logic of it

Comment: @user963241 Note that `std::is_same_v<char, signed char>` is always false even if the `char` is signed, so you can't convert `char *` to `signed char *`.

Comment: How else should I say then? I am sure you know that `char` has to be either `signed char` or `unsigned char` :)

Comment: no, `char` is either unsigned or signed, but neither `usigned char` nor `signed char` :P

Comment: No. `char` has to be either signed or unsigned, but it's always a different type compared to both `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also, you have to use **`const`** `char *cp`, otherwise converting string literals to it ill-formed (since C++11, I think).

Comment: i allowed myself to edit the question to actually have a question. Just roll back in case you dont like it

Comment: There are *3* `char` types in C and C++; `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`. They are all *distinct types* (even if two of them may have overlapping ranges on various platforms). This bit me once, since `char` on AiX (with xlc) and `char` on Linux (with gcc) don't have the same signedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following implementation-defined:
>
> ```
> signed char *cp = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";
> ```
>
> and as well as:
>
> ```
> std::string = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";
> ```

On systems with 8-bits wide signed `char`, yes. A hex escape sequence in a narrow string literal has an implementation-defined value if it falls outside of the implementation-defined range defined for `char`. Assuming 8-bit signed `char`, any hex value greater than `7F` is outside the range of representable values.

Whether that literal is used to initialise a `std::string` or a pointer to character is irrelevant in this regard.

---

You can use an array of `unsigned char` instead of a string literal:

```
static constexpr unsigned char cp[] = {
    0x96,
    0xA0,
    0xB4,
    0xC8,
};
```

You can use this array to initialise a `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` if you need it:

```
 std::basic_string<unsigned char> s = {std::begin(cp), std::end(cp)};
```

---

P.S. Conversion from string literal to non-const char pointer is ill-formed (since C++11; prior the conversion was well-formed but deprecated).

P.P.S `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are always three distinct types whether `char` is signed or not.

Comment: Is it possible to make this well-defined and not dependent on compiler? E.g. I couldn't do this: `unsigned char *cp = "\x96\xA0\xB4\xBE\xC8";` is it necessary?

Comment: @user963241 that doesn't help with making the value of the string literal independent of the compiler. You can use an array instead, as shown in my edit.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is signedness is implementation-defined and also how the value e.g. '\x96' is interpreted is also implementation-defined, but if we do `unsigned char c = '\x96'` then it is well-defined.

Comment: @user963241 Yes, to each statement. Although the correct syntax is `unsigned char c = 0x96`;

Comment: There exists no computer system where a `char` is less than 8 bits or is not two's complement. It looks like C++20 will finally [acknowledge that](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html).

Comment: So when people are using `char *c` with such hex string, aren't they making their code dependent on compiler? Should I try to use `unsigned char` with such hex string?

Comment: @user963241 Yes. You should use an array of `unsigned char`, rather than a string literal if you wish to use values greater than 0x7F and be independent of implementation.

Comment: @rustyx "There exists no computer system where a char is less than 8 bits" - That's plain *not true*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215694/5910058 - Uncommon, yes. Nonexistent, no.

Comment: @rustyx curiously they did not propose to make the hex escape sequences outside the range of `char` well defined, which I suppose they could have proposed given that 2's complement is guaranteed. At least the linked proposal doesn't, nor the latest draft.

Comment: It seems its not possible to do that with `std::string` i.e. be independent of implementation, right? because it will not use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @user963241 I'm not 100% sure about `std::string`. Possibly in C++20 given the guarantee of 2's complement. In that case the values may be in different range than you expect though. `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` is fine for sure; I've added an example.