# Too many realloc calls?

Tags: c

I have the following C code:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
int count = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    str[count] = c;
    count++;
    str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof(str) + sizeof(char));
}
```

But it is throwing the error `Unhandled exception at 0x77C8F94D (ntdll.dll) in algorithms.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted`. I have been trying to solve this for ages, but can't get it right. Interestingly, it is only an issue when the input stream has a large number of characters to be read.

Is this due to my usage of malloc and realloc?

Comment: You don't mean `sizeof(str)` - that's the size of the pointer, not the length of the string. You probably meant `count`.

Comment: You probably mean strlen(str)

Comment: Given `char* str`, just what do you think `sizeof(str)` returns?

Comment: @Nina - Can't use `strlen(str)` because there's no `nul` terminator!

Comment: Besides not using `sizeof` in the `realloc` call, you also want to multiply there, not add.

Comment: Oh yes good call @Adrian

Comment: Probably want "`count * sizeof(char)`"; but really, calling `realloc()` for every single character is awful and you should allocate more less often (e.g. like maybe "`if(count % 4096 == 0) { str = realloc(str, (count + 4096) * sizeof(char)); }`". Also note that `realloc()` could return NULL and you should check for and handle that properly instead of crashing unexpectedly.

Comment: @Brendan I agree that calling `realloc` on every single character is awful, but I've heard that it's not as bad as it could be because the OS will give larger blocks of memory than requested, resulting in system calls being automatically amortized and we're mostly left with the in-process function call overhead to `realloc`. Is this true, and if so, to what extent does it improve the situation? In other words, how awful is it?

Comment: @ggorlen: How expensive each individual `realloc()` is depends on the code responsible (e.g. the implementation of the C system library). For my own personal implementation its fast for some cases (decreasing size) but for increasing the size (beyond the next 32 byte boundary) it falls back to "allocate new block, copy every byte into the new block, free the old block", so as the block gets larger it gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected code below:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
int count = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    str[count] = c;
    count++;
    str = (char*)realloc(str, count * sizeof(char));
}
```

However, this does use too many `realloc` calls! Better to only allocate in blocks, where I've also used the **BPC** principle, rather than **MNC** (see comments):

```
size_t limit = 1024u; // For example!
char* str = malloc(limit);
int count = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    str[count] = c;
    if (++count >= limit) {
        limit += 1024u;
        char *str2 = realloc(str, limit); // Shouldn't use same pointer ...
        if (!str2) { // ... failure!
            // <Some error message/flag>
            break;
        }
        else str = str2; // Successful realloc
    }
}
```

Comment: And it's often better still to use a multiplicative growth scheme, e.g. `limit *= 2`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, in many circumstances multiplicative growth is good; here, I'm not so sure, and I wanted to keep to code simple.

Comment: Even better would be just ```str = (char*)realloc(str, limit);```, since ```sizeof(char) == 1```. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8

Comment: @GasperStukelj Of course, but sometimes putting the explicit `sizeof(type)` in calls makes it clearer to readers what exactly you're allocating. And any (half-)decent compiler would just drop the `* 1`, anyway.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of `malloc`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). If you do need to use `sizeof(type)`, it's better to use `sizeof(*str)` which doesn't hardcode the type.

Comment: Which modern C compilers warn if it's not used? That's surprising.

Comment: You're entitled to that, but if the OP's code has a variety of poor practices, I don't think MNC makes much sense. Why not simply produce the best possible code in any given circumstance (BPC Principle)?

Comment: Can do "`if(count == limit) { ..`" before the `str[count] = c;` to avoid the chance of (re)allocating memory just before EOF, and also avoid the need for the `malloc()` (just do `char *str = NULL;` and let `realloc()` allocate).

Comment: @Brendan On your first point: we don't know what we'll be doing with `str` after we've finished the input loop! If we then append (say) a `nul` character, your suggested optimization would fail.

Comment: @Adrian: LOL. If you're worried about failures, start by checking to see if `realloc()` returned NULL, and maybe think about limiting the max. size (in case some chuckleberry tries to read "`/dev/zero`").

Comment: Agree with Brendan on checking that `malloc`/`realloc` worked. Seems `limit *= 2` is more typical but yes, overflowing `limit` is a risk. I'd definitely remove `sizeof(char)`, it's guaranteed to be 1 and reduces readability (or use `sizeof *str`). But I don't mean to nitpick this small piece of code excessively, it answers OP's question nicely.

Comment: @ggorlen - OK - I surrender!